# Intellisense algorithm for scripting language

Tags: java, algorithm, intellisense, abstract-syntax-tree, scripting-language

I'm building a programmable piece of software. Idea was to let the end users controll the host system through some scripting. Hence the software comes with a script editor for which I'm using **RSyntaxTextArea**. All is well till here.

As a final touch, I thought of adding some sort of **IntelliSense** to the script(The script language is **Rhino**) editor and I'm not sure how exactly to best implement this(at least to some extent).

To get started, I have started with this amateur approach :

1. **.(dot)** character invokes the whole suggestion process.
2. The script content (excluding the current statement) is **eval**uated and from which I identify variables/functions defined so far and their type. The suggestions are computed based on this.

Alternatively instead of evaluating the script(which is premature), I'm thinking about building **AST**. Is this a right way to approach this? Do you have any suggestions/links/algorithms etc.. ? How to handle the case when the current state of the script is not compilable?  Please advice.

Comment: Why is this question tagged Java?

Comment: Rhino is Javascript isn't it? So you are basically asking for an autocomplete algorithm for Javascript.

Comment: Here's an old question discussing intellisense for dynamically typed languages which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020096/intellisense-for-dynamic-languages

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are implementing this in Java (due to the java tag) you should take a look at [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) it incorporates the lexer, AST handling capabilities and even code generation (although this last part maybe irrelevante to you).

Comment: Well, you need to know what variables have been defined and whatnot, so unless there is an already-available solution, you will have to implement an interpreter for your scripting language. I would prefer doing this by writing the grammar myself ( depends on how complex the language is), and once that's done, you can implement some functions to get variables of an object, and all that jazz.